# Is there a way to add ui elements from code in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

In netlogo, the way to  add say, a button is to click on the add button and select button demonstrated [here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/tutorial3.html). is there a way to do this from code, say when the setup button is clicked? I want to generate some monitors demonstrating some information after the setup button is clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [eXtraWidgets extension](https://github.com/CRESS-Surrey/eXtraWidgets#readme) allows you to create additional interface tabs in the NetLogo GUI and programatically put custom widgets on them.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work (yet) with NetLogo 6.0.

There also used to be the [Goo extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/Goo-Extension), but it has been unmaintained for a while.

Comment: Awesome, I attempted to use it but netlogo doesn't seem to recognize it in my extensions folder. I'm running netlogo 5.3 on Mac OS sierra and I'm getting " Can't find "xw" extension folder ", any ideas? I also tried putting the xw folder in the same directory as the project